# Can I claim my daughter as a dependent on my 2014 tax return even though she got married in August?

Tags: taxes, children, tuition, marriage, dependents

Can I claim my daughter as a dependent on my 2014 tax return even though she got married in August? She did not live at home but was a full-time student for at least 5 months out of the year, and we payed for her tuition.

Comment: What country are you in?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on whether or not she files a joint return. If not, you can claim her, if she does, you cannot. See the link below for more info on whether she counts as a "Qualifying Child" in various situations.

[http://www.irs.gov/uac/A-“Qualifying-Child”](http://www.irs.gov/uac/A-%E2%80%9CQualifying-Child%E2%80%9D)

Answer (score 1):

From [reading this document](http://www.irs.gov/uac/A-%E2%80%9CQualifying-Child%E2%80%9D), she would have had to:

- Live at home for more than six months out of the year.
- Be between the ages of 19 and 24 **and** be a full-time student - check her transcripts for the year to see if her credit-hours per semester would have made her a full-time student.
- Not file jointly with her spouse.

If she's not stayed with you at home for at least that long, then she cannot be claimed.

If you're concerned about the tuition, there are [available tax forms](http://www.irs.gov/uac/Tax-Benefits-for-Education:-Information-Center) which can reduce your taxable income by the amount of tuition you've paid, or even give you a bonus.  Her educational institution should have provided her with a Form 1098-T, so be sure that you get a copy of them before you do your taxes.